# Indian citizen travelling to Belize

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, belize, dutch-residents

I am an Indian citizen resident in the Netherlands on a student residence permit. I wish to travel to Belize for a party. I understand I need a clearence, but do I need a visa for Belize or am I exempted due to my EU residence permit ?

Comment: Is this permite a card-type or is it a sticker/stamp on your passport?

Comment: All Dutch residence permits are issued in card format.

Comment: It is going to be an expensive party for the [repatriation fee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Belize#Repatriation_fee) you are due as an Indian citizen.

Answer (score 2):

> Passengers with a valid visa issued by a Schengen Member State, for a
>   maximum stay of 90 days.

[International Air Transport Association](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=BZ&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=GF&subuser=GFB2C)

List of Schengen Member States.

[Schengen Member States](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-countries-list/)

> Passengers with a valid visa issued by a Schengen Member State are
>   visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Belize#Substitute_visa)

Comment: Could you please quote the relevant parts of the links?

Comment: Also is a residence permit here considered the same as a visa?

Comment: @mts, I am also concerned about this.

Comment: Updated answer to quote the relative parts of the pages

Comment: @Uzzide is there no visa Issued in your passport that you needed for entry to the Netherlands before you got your resident permit? I know for my UK Visa I got a 30 day entry clearance visa then I had to collect my residence permit. You could get in touch with the Belize Consulate in the Netherlands to make sure. email: roos@yepro.nl phone: (+31) (20) 408 11 75

Comment: @SamJones I was issued a D category entry visa too for the initial 3 months, but its expired now.

Comment: @Uzzide Id get in touch with the Belize Consulate to be 100% sure